# How to delete selected row from Datagridview and Access DB in .NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I am trying to delete selected row from datagridview and commit changes permanently in my access DB here is my code:

```
     cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Accountcode.accdb;"
    cn.Open()

    Try
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
            Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Accountcode.accdb;")
                Using cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
                    cm.Connection = cn
                    cm.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM CheckDJ WHERE [ID]= @id"
                    cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", CType(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row("ID"))
                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Accountcode.accdb;")
            Using cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
                strsql = "SELECT * FROM CheckDJ"
                cm.Connection = cn
                cm.CommandText = strsql
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text

                Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(strsql, cn)
                Dim ds As New DataSet()
                da.Fill(ds, "CheckDJ")
                DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

But I'm having an error. 
 
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's because you are removing rows while iterating them. Throw them in a collection first, then loop through each one and remove it from the datagridview and then remove it from the database. Currently your in a loop to remove records from datagridview but you are requiring the database and filling the datagridview again inside this loop, that is bad practice and asking for problems... Also use parameters and look into properly disposing connection objects, commands etc...Open connection do your work and the close and cleanup.

Comment: @Zaggler I would appreciate it very much if you can help me by showing me the correct code. You can modify my code.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b see my edited code above

Answer (score 1):

```
Try
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DatagridView1.SelectedRows
            Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Accountcode.accdb;")
                Using cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
                    cm.Connection = cn
                    cm.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM CheckDJ WHERE [ID]= @id"
                    cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ctype(row.DataBoundItem,DataRowView).Row("id"))
                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\Accountcode.accdb;")
            Using cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
                    strsql = "SELECT * FROM CheckDJ"
                    cm.Connection = cn
                    cm.CommandText = strsql
                    cm.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(strsql, cn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds, "CheckDJ")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
           End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I got this error trying your code.

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b This line:  cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ctype(row.DataBoundItem,DataRowView).Row("id"))

Comment: change the "id" in Row("id") to the actual name of your column

Answer (score 0):

You're going about that all wrong.  Firstly, use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` and bind that to the grid.  You would then get the bound `DataRowView` from each selected row in the grid, call its `Delete` method to mark it as `Deleted` (which will remove it from the grid) and then use the same data adapter to save the changes back to the database.  E.g.

```
myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataTable)
myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable

'...

Dim rowsToDelete As New List(Of DataRowView)

For Each gridRow As DataGridViewRow In myDataGridView.SelectedRows
    rowsToDelete.Add(DirectCast(gridRow.DataBoundItem, DataRowView))
Next

For Each row In rowsToDelete
    row.Delete()
Next

myDataAdapter.Update(myDataTable)
```

Comment: I wondered about the DV myself. I do wish such people would leave a comment. If there's something that needs changing then we're not going to change it if we don't know what it is.